Current ratio for autotransformer (model does not give expected ratio)
I am trying to model an autotransformer circuit, treating it as two coupled inductors (common magnetic core) with a resistive load on the secondary.  I am having trouble getting the answer I expect, which that secondary current is primary current divided by the turns ratio of the two inductors.
The circuit is roughly what is used for AC current measurement in some analog multimeters. Here is the circuit (simplified from this already-simplified meter schematic):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I do some calculation (see below for detail) and come out with:
$$ 
I_2 = \frac{I}{\sqrt{[R / (\omega(L_1-M))]^2 + [(L_2-M)/(L_1-M)+1]^2}}\cos(\omega t + \phi)
$$
where \$\phi\$ is some arctan function (not important here).
Considering the case of \$R=0\$, perfect coupling of the inductors \$(M = \sqrt{L_1 L_2})\$, and \$L_2 >> L_1\$, the expression simplifies (more details below) to:
$$ 
I_2 \approx \sqrt{\frac{L_1}{L_2 }} I_0
$$
modulo some phase shift.
If I make the assumption that turn spacing is constant across both inductors then I expect \$L_1 / L_2 = N_1 / N_2\$ (inductance is proportional to turns-squared but coil length is proportional to turns so the overall ratio is just turns).  In that case:
$$ 
I_2 \approx \sqrt{\frac{N_1}{N_2}} I_0
$$
But I am expecting:
$$ 
I_2 \approx \frac{N_1}{N_2} I_0
$$
which is the common ratio given by many websites for a standard autotransformer and is the only way I can make sense of the real-world meter schematics.
What am I missing?
Here is the more detailed maths:
From Kirchoff/Faraday’s laws:
$$
V = L_1 \frac{\mathrm{d}I_1}{\mathrm{d}t} + M \frac{\mathrm{d}I_2}{\mathrm{d}t} 
$$
and
$$
V = L_2 \frac{\mathrm{d}I_2}{\mathrm{d}t} + M \frac{\mathrm{d}I_1}{\mathrm{d}t} + I_2 R
$$
Taking Laplace transforms:
$$
\mathcal{L}(V(t))(s) = L_1 s \mathcal{L}(I_1)  + Ms\mathcal{L}(I_2)
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{L}(V(t))(s) = L_2 s \mathcal{L}(I_2)  + Ms\mathcal{L}(I_1) + R\mathcal{L}(I_2)
$$
From which:
$$
\mathcal{L}(I_1) = \frac{L_2-M}{L_1-M}\mathcal{L}(I_2) + \frac{R}{L_1-M}\frac{1}{s}\mathcal{L}(I_2) \\ = \frac{L_2-M}{L_1-M}\mathcal{L}(I_2) + \frac{R}{L_1-M}\mathcal{L}(1)\mathcal{L}(I_2) \\ = \frac{L_2-M}{L_1-M}\mathcal{L}(I_2) + \frac{R}{L_1-M}\mathcal{L}(1 \ast I_2)
$$
and then taking the inverse of the Laplace transform:
$$
I_1(t) = \frac{L_2-M}{L_1-M}I_2 + \frac{R}{L_1-M} \int_0^t{I_2(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau}
$$
Assume the total input current is a sinusoid:
$$
I_0 = I_1 + I_2 = I \cos (\omega t)
$$
Then
$$
I \cos (\omega t) = \left(\frac{L_2-M}{L_1-M} + 1\right)I_2 + \frac{R}{L_1-M} \int_0^t{I_2(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau}
$$
Differentiating gives:
$$
-\omega I \sin (\omega t) = \left(\frac{L_2-M}{L_1-M} + 1\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}I_2}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{R}{L_1-M} I_2
$$
which is an ordinary differential equation in \$I_2\$.  Solving in Wolfram Alpha and simplifying a bit gives:
$$
I_2 = \frac{I}{\sqrt{[R/(\omega(L_1-M))]^2 + [(L_2-M)/(L_1-M)+1]^2}}\cos(\omega t + \phi)
$$
for some phase-shift \$\phi\$ that I don’t care about.  If there is perfect coupling of the inductors (\$M = \sqrt{L_1 L_2}\$) and \$L_2>>L_1\$ then
$$
\frac{L_2-M}{L_1-M} + 1 = \sqrt{\frac{L_2}{L_1}} + 1 \approx \sqrt{\frac{L_2}{L_1}}
$$
In which case:
$$
I_2 = \frac{I}{\sqrt{[R/(\omega(L_1-M))]^2 + \frac{L_2}{L_1}}}
$$

What you're missing it that the \$L\$ is proptional to \$N^2\$
so \${{L_1}^2\over{L_2}^2} = {{N_1}\over{N_2}}\$

It's also proportional to 1/length and I assume the same turn spacing on both inductors (i.e. turns = constant x length).  Doesn't that make L proportional to N in this case?

@Tony L is never proportional to N, always proportional to N². Unless the individual turns are on separate cores and thus totally uncoupled, anyway.

length only matters for air core inductors.  if there a ferromagnetic core that will dominate.
